# matlab flip matrix

Tags: matlab

Lets say i have a matrix.

```
A = [
   8     9     14     0     0     0     0     0     0

   8    10    11     0     0     0     0     0     0

   5     8     9    14     0     0     0     0     0

   7     8     9    14     0     0     0     0     0

   5     8    10    11     0     0     0     0     0
 ];
```

How do i flip the matrix and get such result in matlab? I do not want it in sorted order.Thank you

```
A = [
 14     9    8     0     0     0     0     0     0

 11    10    8     0     0     0     0     0     0

 14    9     8     5     0     0     0     0     0

 14    9     8     7     0     0     0     0     0

 11    10    8     5     0     0     0     0     0
];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Will this always end with sorted rows? If so you could use sort(A,2,'descend').

Comment: Are you trying to flip an entire row? Order the values in a row from largest to smallest? It *looks* like you're just ordering them, because you ignore all the `0` cells.

Comment: sorry i just realize that i don't want it to be in sorted row. i just want to reverse the whole matrix. example matrix = ...
[ 1 5 1 0 0 ;
  6 2 3 1 0 
  ] will have result matrix = ...
[ 1 5 1 0 0 ;
  1 3 2 6 0 
  ]

Answer (score 4):

No resizing needed, if you want to flip columns 1 through 4 you can use the following:

```
colList = 1:4;

matrix(:,colList) = fliplr(matrix(:,colList));
```

This will work for any arbitrary list of columns

**How it works**

First select the columns you care about with:

```
   ... matrix(:,colList)
```

Reflect them horizontally with

```
   ... fliplr( ... )
```

Save the reflected matrix back into sub section of the original matrix with:

```
matrix(:,colList) =  ...
```

Comment: This won't work, since there are some rows with only three non-zero entries.

Comment: @Jonas hmm.. I didn't notice that some rows had 3 values.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, I think you want the following:

1. Find the last non-zero element in each row, call it lastNZ
2. Reverse the order of elements 1:lastNZ in the row

This should do the job:

```
for i=1:size(A,1)
    lastNZ = find(A(i,:), 1, 'last');
    A(i,1:lastNZ) = A(i,lastNZ:-1:1);
end
```

Comment: Although, if you never have any embedded zeros in the rows, ioums solution will work quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you don't want the rows to end up sorted slayton's response will work with a small change to account for the different number of zeroes. Something like:

```
for i=1:size(A,1)  
    temp = A(i,A(i,:)~=0);  
    A(i,A(i,:)~=0) = fliplr(temp);  
end
```

If you want a one line solution (which will probably not be any faster than the for loop, and is more confusing to read) you could use

```
A = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) [fliplr(x(x~=0)) zeros(1,size(x,2)-nnz(x))],num2cell(A,2),'UniformOutput',false))
```

I am making the assumption that your matrices do not have any zeroes that are a part of the reordering (such as  [ 1 5 1 0 0 ; 6 0 3 1 0 ] going to [ 1 5 1 0 0 ; 1 3 0 6 0 ]). If that assumption is incorrect then my code needs to be changed.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This work great! Thank you so much for your time again.and no i will not have zero in between the number. i only put the zero at the end so that the matrix will be even in dimensions.